# Prompt JavaScript If Else Unexpected Token else

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax-error, prompt

I'm teaching myself JavaScript using Code Academy and I'm trying to make some simple code so that when prompt asks a question, the user reply gives a response.

example.

```
prompt says "what's your favourite colour?"

user says "blue"

response "that's the same colour as the sky!"
```

But when I try to add different options, I get  Syntax error: unexpected token else.

I tried making it so that if I asked a question, the reply gets a response but anything else gets a response.

Here's the code.

```
prompt("what do you want?");

if ("coke");
{console.log ("no coke, pepsi.")};
else
console.log ("pepsi only.")};
```

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't work for Coca Cola.

You need to save the return value of `prompt` if you want to use it later. Also, you have some syntax errors that should be corrected:

```
var answer = prompt('what do you want?');

if (answer === 'coke') {
    console.log('you said coke!');
} else {
    console.log('why didn\'t you say coke!?');
}
```

You could also use a switch as you get more cases:

```
var answer = prompt('what do you want?');

switch (answer) {
    case 'coke':
        console.log('you said coke!');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('why didn\'t you say coke!?');
        break;
}
```

Or an object, as most people prefer this to switch:

```
var answer = prompt('what do you want?');

var responses = {
    coke: 'you said coke!',
    defaultResponse: 'why didn\'t you say coke!?'
};

console.log(responses[answer] || responses.defaultResponse);
```

Answer (score 5):

The if does not need a semicolon at the end.  Instead do:

```
if ("coke") {
    console.log ("no coke, pepsi.");
} else {
    console.log ("pepsi only.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the trailing semicolons:

```
prompt("what do you want?");

if ("coke") {
    console.log ("no coke, pepsi.");
} else {
    console.log ("pepsi only.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a semi-colon after the close brace. Try:

```
var ans = prompt("what do you want?");

if (ans == "coke") {
    console.log ("no coke, pepsi.");
} else {
    console.log ("pepsi only.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var name = prompt("what do you want?");  
if (name == "coke") 
{
console.log ("no coke, pepsi.")
}
else 
{
console.log ("pepsi only.")
}
```

Like above

Answer (score 0):

Actually DO NOT do

```
 if (ans == "whatever") {
    console.log ("whatever");
} else {
    console.log ("whatever.");
}
```

DO

```
 if (ans == "whatever") {
    confirm ("whatever");
} else {
    confirm ("whatever.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `variable` needs to be identified. Also the bracketing and the semi colons between the `"if" "else"` statements are problematic. I am not sure about the `console log`, but if you want a **popup** alert try this:

```
var brand = prompt ('what do you want?');
if (brand="coke") {
   alert ("no coke, pepsi.")
}else {
   alert ("pepsi only.")
};
```

DICLAIMER: I am novice at best, jut happened to debug a similar issue.
Hope it helps.