# just need to Verify -- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am not a js programmer and I have this issue (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else)

on one of our pages ...

I strongly believe this is a duplicate of 2 Questions that were answered around this place:

1) [Syntax Error: Unexpected token Else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21500439/syntax-error-unexpected-token-else)
2) [Prompt JavaScript If Else Unexpected Token else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963350/prompt-javascript-if-else-unexpected-token-else)

So I admit my sin ... (But) I must verify my case is the same %100 for sure( a trailing ; )

So the script is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if("0" == 0) var t = 'existing' else var t = 'new';
document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="//my.domain.com/tag.js?ck=XXX&Retarget=domain:'+t+':psd:sku:XXXXXXXX"></scr'+'ipt>');
</script>
```

in Chrome .... the error shows after the if statement

Comment: Use `{}` around your `if` and `else` blocks.  Trust me.  It'll make your life 1,000,000x easier.

Comment: Just to know, why are you comparing zero to zero? `Else` will never be performed.

Comment: @AlieN: It was probably generated via PHP (or other server-side) code.

Comment: indeed it makes no sense to do that compare ..  I think @RocketHazmat is right ... not sure though

Comment: @user3459272: Isn't this your code?  You don't know where it came from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `;` after your command. If you use more than one command in a line you have to end the command with `;`
It should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if("0" == 0) var t = 'existing'; else var t = 'new';
document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="//my.domain.com/tag.js?ck=XXX&Retarget=domain:'+t+':psd:sku:XXXXXXXX"></scr'+'ipt>');
</script>
```

Anyway: Here you see a good reason to use brackets `{}` instead of the short version

Answer (score 2):

```
if("0" == 0) var t = 'existing'; else var t = 'new';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if("0" == 0) 
{
   var t = 'existing'; 
}
else 
{
   var t = 'new';
}
```

Although this is very strange that you are comparing `"0" == 0`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its better to create an inline if to set "t" and this also solves your problem

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var t = ("0" == 0) ? 'existing' : 'new';
        document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="//my.domain.com/tag.js?ck=XXX&Retarget=domain:'+t+':psd:sku:XXXXXXXX"></scr'+'ipt>');
    </script>
```